# How can I check if there is a query string from a Ruby on Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-string

I'm using pagination on our Ruby on Rails app and the pages are defined in the request with a query string parameter like

```
http://ourdomain.com/?page=2
```

I use this on our front page where there's no page number explicitly defined.

I'd like to do a check to see if there is a query string, and if not then display the correct page=1, by redirecting to that page I presume

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks ahead for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if params[:page].blank?
  redirect_to :page => 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! Any hints for getting this working with a layout being specified as well?

Comment: Do you want the layout to be part of the URL? (e.g http://ourdomain.com/?page=2&layout=funky)

Answer (score 13):

Simply check,

```
if request.query_string.present? 
  # Do your stuff here.
end
```

Thats it ! Cheers!!!!

Comment: Using `present?` to test whether a query string exists or not. Using `blank?` to test whether the value of a query string exists or not.

Comment: Correct @Hong. I agree with you!