# Rails - Using Posts#Index View to show only 'Liked' Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Since the index view for `posts` has the same code, I have an action in the Posts controller #liked, which save all of the current_user's liked posts. I am trying to `redirect_to posts_path(@posts)`, but for some reason the index view still has `@posts` returning all posts..? I'm sure there is some sort of rails magic happening here.

I already checked my #liked method and it is successfully saving only liked posts in `@posts`, but the redirect is simply not passing `@posts` from this action, but rather from the original #index action.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Austin Burke, I am assuming you have following two methods in posts controller:

`def posts
  @posts = Post.all
end`

And a second method:

`def liked
  @liked_posts = [post1, post2]
end`

You should do:

`def posts
  @liked_posts = Post.where(liked: true)
end`

The reason is you are using `redirect_to posts_path(@posts)` which calls index method of posts controller. This index method of posts controller should take `@liked_posts` with it.

Comment: Ahh okay. I knew it would be something simple.. I do wish there was a way to keep it  where I only need `@posts`. I will have to write the exact same code in the index twice with the only difference being the instance variable using the method you defined.

Comment: Would there be a way to pass some special parameter through my "View liked posts" button so the controller action knows to not assign `@posts = Post.all` and instead `@posts = current_user.liked_posts`?

Comment: @AustinBurke yes this is possible. You can pass query parameters from your request. This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888946/how-can-i-check-if-there-is-a-query-string-from-a-ruby-on-rails-controller/21548815

Comment: @AustinBurke If my answer fulfilled your requirement then please accept my answer with an upvote :) Thank you.